# Running Grails Commands Over SSH

Tags: java, grails, groovy, ssh

I'm trying to automate running tests on a remote server over SSH (Windows - via Cygwin) but I'm not having any luck.  I tried the following:

```
/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/cmd.exe /c grails test-app unit
```

And get the following:

**ERROR: Environment variable JAVA_HOME has not been set.**

I've tried putting this into a .bat file like so:

```
cd c:\{redacted}\{redacted}\{my project}

SET JAVA_HOME=c:\java\jdk1.7.0_65
SET GRAILS_HOME=c:\grails\2.1.1

grails test-app -unit --stacktrace --verbose --non-interactive
```

Which results in the following:

**Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"**

Has anyone successfully run Grails tests over SSH that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: does it actually work on the windows box in a terminal?

Comment: Yep, works fine if I run from CMD line on the box.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has an SSH client for running commands on a different server.  Also the documentation talks about using an Cygwin SSH server which might be helpful.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+slaves+and+Cygwin